# Geotiff Mollweide and geotools

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotools

I am new to GIS and I want to read population data from a GeoTiff Grid using the java geotools library.

The following throws a runtime error

```
GridCoverage2D image  = new GeoTiffReader(f);
```

gives

```
Error message: GeoTiffMetadata2CRSAdapter::createCoordinateSystem:Only
Geographic & Projected Systems are supported.
```

Is there a way to have geotools to use Mollweide ?
Or can I convert the tiff file ?

Below is the gdalinfo.

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: GHS_POP_GPW42015_GLOBE_R2015A_54009_1k_v1_0.tif
       GHS_POP_GPW42015_GLOBE_R2015A_54009_1k_v1_0.tif.ovr
       GHS_POP_GPW42015_GLOBE_R2015A_54009_1k_v1_0.tif.aux.xml
Size is 35497, 15236
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["World_Mollweide",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
Origin = (-17619594.547443531453609,8751029.461868489161134)
Pixel Size = (1000.000000000000000,-1000.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-17619594.547, 8751029.462) (  5d15'16.97"W, 83d38'22.73"N)
Lower Left  (-17619594.547,-6484970.538) (107d 3'58.73"E, 55d59' 2.97"S)
Upper Right (17877405.453, 8751029.462) ( 15d52' 0.05"E, 83d38'22.73"N)
Lower Right (17877405.453,-6484970.538) (103d21'55.35"W, 55d59' 2.97"S)
Center      (  128905.453, 1133029.462) (  1d17'47.25"E,  9d10'43.07"N)
```

SOLUTION from @IanTurton:

I created a epsg.properties file with the line indicated by Ian.
And added the following code:

```
   URL epsg = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("epsg.properties"); 
          if (epsg != null) { 
           Hints hints =  
            new Hints(Hints.CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY, PropertyAuthorityFactory.class); 
           ReferencingFactoryContainer referencingFactoryContainer =  
            ReferencingFactoryContainer.instance(hints); 
           PropertyAuthorityFactory factory; 
            factory = new PropertyAuthorityFactory( 
                            referencingFactoryContainer, 
                            Citations.fromName("EPSG"), 
                            epsg); 
            ReferencingFactoryFinder.addAuthorityFactory(factory); 
            ReferencingFactoryFinder.scanForPlugins();
} 
          else throw new IOException("properties not found");
```

Comment: it still does not work. I will post a new question

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use Mollweide has been in [GeoTools and GeoServer](https://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developers-corner-adding-two-global-equal-area-projections-to-geotoolsgeoserver/) for sometime 
but you have to add the definition to the local projections file as it is not a standard EPSG projection.

You need to add

```
54009=PROJCS[“World_Mollweide”, GEOGCS[“WGS_1984″,DATUM[“WGS_1984″,SPHEROID[“WGS_1984″,6378137.0,298.257223563]], PRIMEM[“Greenwich”,0.0],UNIT[“Degree”,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[“Mollweide”], PARAMETER[“Central_Meridian”,0.0],UNIT[“Meter”,1.0]] 54012=PROJCS[“World_Eckert_IV”,  GEOGCS[“WGS_1984″,DATUM[“WGS_1984″,SPHEROID[“WGS_1984″,6378137.0,298.257223563]], PRIMEM[“Greenwich”,0.0],UNIT[“Degree”,0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[“Eckert_IV”], PARAMETER[“Central_Meridian”,0.0],UNIT[“Meter”,1.0]]
```

to your `epgs.properties` file. You'll need to include `gt-epsg-wkt` module, there are instructions in the [referencing FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html).